# javascript not getting data from sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, client-object-model, sharepoint-library

I tried the below code from MSDN

```
function retrieveListItems() {

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext('http://www.vignesh.cloudappsportal.com');
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('EmailId');
    clientContext.load(oList);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
    function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
        SPListItems.push(sender); // pushing values into a global array to check in console
        SPListItems.push(args);
    }

    function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
        alert('fail')
    }
}
```

oList is getting some values, but i get error in `this.onQuerySucceeded`

`this` is referring to window and so there is no function like `this.onQuerySucceeded`

Comment: Are you running the JavaScript within SharePoint environment?

Comment: And are there a list with the title EmailId?

Comment: Are you using plane .aspx page  (i.e. page without sharepoint master page) ?

Comment: @ArsalanAdamKhatri  yeah, the script is inside sharepoint app

Comment: @RohitWaghela its a sharepoint app

Comment: @RobertLindgren yes I have created it and it has data too

Answer (score 5):

You are missing a couple of rows in a working script. First, after setting the oList variable you need to load it:

```
clientContext.load(oList);
```

Then you need to fetch the value by calling:

```
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
    Function.createDelegate(this, onQuerySucceeded), 
    Function.createDelegate(this, onQueryFailed)
);
```

Now, you need to create the following two methods (for success and failure of the execution):

```
 function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args){
     // here you can work with oList
 }

 function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('fail')
 }
```

Comment: Thanks @robert  will the args in onQuerySucceeded have the list of items under the column?

Comment: Please check my updated question

Comment: this is referring to window when i checked in console

Comment: Remove the `this`from the create delegate, as I have done in my update answer

Answer (score 1):

If your ultimate goal is to get SharePoint list items using JavaScript, then you can refer below set of functions.

Also you can refer this useful msdn [blog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185007(v=office.14).aspx).

```
        function getListItems () {
            try {
                var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext('http://www.vignesh.cloudappsportal.com');
                var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('EmailId');
                var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
                this.collListItems = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
                clientContext.load(collListItems); 
                clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onSuccess, onFail);
            }
            catch (err) {
                alert('Error while getting list items');
            }
        }

        function onSuccess () {
            var listItemEnumerator = collListItems.getEnumerator();
            while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
                alert(oListItem.get_item('Title'));
            }
        }

        function onFail (sender, args) {
            alert(args.get_message());
        }
```